# Eclipse keeps crunching while "updating rpm packages proposal list"

Tags: eclipse, windows-7, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-kepler

I've recently installed Eclipse Kepler CDT on a Win7 64 machine. It runs fine (well, sort of), but - it keeps crunching, with the status bar saying

> Updating RPM packages proposal list

Why is this happening and how can I make it stop?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

It's a [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=361862) in the "Linux Tools" plugin.
It seems that the plugin is unable to create the file specified at

> **Window -> Preferences -> Specfile Editor -> RPM Completions -> Path to packages list file**

or

> **Window -> Preferences -> RPM -> Specfile Editor -> RPM Completions -> Path to packages list file**

and therefore keeps trying to create it.

To fix this problem, just create an empty file at that location & name, or create a new empty file at a different location & name and specify it as the "Path to packages list file".

**Note:** You cannot create the default file (`.pkglist`) using Windows explorer since it won't let you create a file whose name starts with a dot. So open a console (command prompt) window and run this command:

```
echo. > path\to\file\.pkglist
```

Comment: But why would I have a 'Linux Tools' plugin on Windows?

Comment: I guess they are installed by default in the Eclipse IDE for C/C++ developers because I had the same problem and didn't install them explicitly either.

Comment: If you have Cygwin Installed, you can create a `.pkglist` file in that just fine.

Comment: To easily create the file from CMD: `echo. > path\to\file\.pkglist` (Close Eclipse first).

Comment: @Alberto Thanks for that suggestion; I edited the answer with that information. BTW I didn't even have to close Eclipse first; as soon as I created that file, suddenly Eclipse stopped churning with that "updating RPM packages proposal list" message.

Comment: Worked for me, I've just created `.pkglist` file in the eclipse folder and changed the Path unter RPM Completions. Have had this problem since 2020/03 Update

Answer (score 20):

I was able to solve this in Eclipse Kepler by going to `Window -> Preferences -> Specfile Editor -> RPM Completions` and un-checking `Automatically build the RPM packages proposal list`

Comment: Thanks this works! However, in Eclipse 2022-06, this option is hidden under Window --> Preferences --> RPM --> Specfile Editor --> RPM completions

Answer (score 3):

Run Eclipse as administrator and it will create this fail successfully. Normal program do not have rights to write into this directory.

When developers lean to give meaningful error messages? Also, it will probably tray to write into this file sometimes in the future and that will also fail. Make this fail writable for users, normally programs run with user rights!

Comment: I didn't have admin privileges, unfortunately.

Comment: Is it safe to run Eclipse with admin privileges?

Answer (score 2):

In Eclipse version 2022-06, the updating can be disabled by goin to `Window -> Preferences -> RPM -> Specfile Editor -> RPM Completions` (note the first **RPM** which is not present in Eclipse Kepler) and un-checking `Automatically build the RPM packages proposal list`

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this simply because my %USERPROFILE%.pkglist didn't exist, so creating the empty file solved the problem for me.